# DAOS Estimator - run on large lotus notes database

Tags: ibm-domino

I have implemented DAOS on mail files (on a Lotus Domino Server), but not on a bespoke notes application.  The estimator (version 1.5) keeps crashing when I try to run it on a 40Gb and 60Gb database (both have loads of attachments).

3 questions:

- Can I run DAOS on a non Notes mail database?
- If some of the data is archived to another database, on the same server, then will the link to the data be preserved?
- Should I be concerned implementing, without having a chance to run the estimator first?

Thanks

Comment: Details - what kind of DB are you trying to run DAOS against?  And how are you archiving the data?

Comment: Archiving is done via an agent, simple copy to another db and then delete.  Both databases are on the same server.  The DB is a Notes DB, just a custom app.  All fairly standard Notes functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I run DAOS on a non Notes mail database? ... The DB is a Notes DB, just a custom app.

Yes.  In fact, [IBM released a fix for the issue of DAOS crashing when running on large databases](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/NotesDomino_8.5.2_FP3_Fix_List)... it's included in 8.5.2 FP3 - might be worth checking out.

> If some of the data is archived to another database, on the same server, then will the link to the data be preserved?

Not the way you're archiving them, no.  "Archiving is done via an agent, simple copy to another db and then delete."

If you're deleting it, it gets deleted.

> Should I be concerned implementing, without having a chance to run the estimator first?

I would be.  But I'm weird like that, wanting to test things before I roll them into production.

Comment: Thanks @HopelessN00b.  How should the archiving be done to ensure this would work.  I was hoping that the CopyToDatabase LotusScript method would ensure that the attachments would copy successfully.

Comment: @SydxPages I'm honestly not sure.  Maybe you should ask another question in that vein to try to smoke out a Notes admin who would know.

Comment: If anyone wants to follow this, then the link to the StackOverflow query can be found here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064894/how-to-archive-data-in-lotus-domino-db-and-keep-attachments-stored-in-daos

Comment: Hi @HopelessN00b - quick follow up on this item.  I have got 8.5.3 FP2 installed and the estimator (1.5) still crashes.  I'm going to bring the server down and run a test on the database on the weekend of DAOS actually running.